# Home automation appliances wired to micro controller with wireless control from ipad/iphone

Tags: microcontroller, relay, iphone, device, home-automation

I'm currently going to start developing a media controller for my room. This microcontroller would be controlled wirelessly from my ipad.
so there's three parts to this, my ipad, simple microcontroller probably would be hidden somewhere in my room, and then the physical controllable parts connected to the controller such as lights and air conditioner.

I understand microcontroller would have a few relays to handle different voltage circuits, some wireless transmitter to accept incoming connections from the ipad, and then some chip or something that would PWM - pulse width modulate - the temperature of the air conditioner. Atleast that is how I would imagine you would control the temperature of the air conditioner.

I have found things on the net that allows me to control things wirelessly, such as those small wireless arduino chips that would communicate with other arduino chips connected to the device itself. I didn't want to take this route since I'd rather have wires hidden connected directly into my microcontroller. The only thing that I would want to make wireless is the connection from my ipad to the microcontroller.

Can someone give me some direction in the best way forward in being able to learn how to create an home automation system, mainly in the field of which microcontrollers to use that would avoid the use of arduinos.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? You ask for chips. What are the requirements? We're not going to do your work.

Comment: Please read my post again, I've shortened it and made more clear my question, I'm essentially requesting for some direction in creating my own home automation system. Some learning tools and learning material that would give me knowledge in how to start building.

Comment: Virtually any MCU could be used. You need to design the system yourself, we won't do it for you. Your question is likely to be closed unless you make it much more specific.

Comment: @Leon Heller: oh bwoi. I'm not asking for you guys to do the system for me. Stop being rude and please just read the post properly and thoroughly to understand what it is that I actually am asking for. I'm just asking from professionals, or anyone within the field of home automation, where the best tools are for learning to be able to finally build what I described in my post.

Comment: How do you propose to communicate between the iPad and the controller? You need to sort that out first. What do you mean by "tools"? Asking for that sort of thing is off-topic.

Comment: @LeonHeller: Hey, so there are two ways that I have thought of for possible communication between the iPad and the controller: 1) either a web back end, or 2) if possible, directly through a WiFi chip to which the device would be paired.

Comment: WiFi might be easiest, and lots of MCUs could be used. Bluetooth is another option. What do you mean by "tools"?

Comment: From our FAQ, we answer "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." Pointers to other web resources are not considered good answers here, so questions that ask for them are not a good fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like this is what you are trying to do:
[image: Wireless Controller]
There are so many different aspects to this project, you cannot just post such an open ended question like this and expect anyone to help you! Do you know anything about RF signals? About microcontroller hardware and software? Do you know how to control an AC device from a small signal circuit? Do you know how to interface into existing circuits such as an air conditioner control module? None of this is trivial or for beginners, and no one is going to spend the time to teach you how to do all of it. You cannot follow a guide to do these things correctly, you have to already know what you plan to do and how to do it. Then you can ask people for help on a specific topic within the project.

Sorry if I sound rude. I would like to help, in fact everyone here would like to help, that's why they are on this website. Based on your question, no one has any idea what you know how to do or what you are trying to do, so it is pretty impossible to offer any suggestions.

Comment: I see, well Kurt I appreciate you taking the time to make me aware of the simple fact that it is a big project indeed. So start small and then increment and implement to the project until I reach my final goal. I thought there may have been a tutorial or learning material in creating a "hello world" example for simple circuit controls for devices. 

So maybe I could start off with connecting a desk lamp connected to a relay connected to the microcontroller; and then have it controllable with the computer through usb -> eventually add wifi chip -> create control from ipad. Thanks for the intro.

Comment: Right. Start small, then when you encounter a problem, ask for help with that. Figure out how everything will work individually, then put it all together.

Comment: Good idea to start small. Many projects are easy to conceptualise, but hard to execute. Especially when one has little knowledge of the area, they cannot imagine any problems and so expect an simple answer.